# To get the code view in Java with ResultSet.getNString or getString. Does not return the complete string from DBA_VIEWS.text

Tags: java, oracle, resultset

I'm trying to get the code view (Oracle), in java with resultset. But when I use the `getString` or `getNString` function, I only get a chain of 32K characters.
The length of the views is greater than 100K characters.

I use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_VIEWS
```

Please help.

Comment: See also: [Streaming LONG or LONG RAW Columns](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jstreams.htm#JJDBC28411).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with ResultSet.getBinariToString, this function take all characters of dba_views.text. Thank you for all.

```
public String getBinaryToString(String columna){
    try {
            java.io.InputStream is = resultados.getBinaryStream(columna);
            int intValueOfChar;
            String targetString = "";
            while ((intValueOfChar = is.read()) != -1) {
                targetString += (char) intValueOfChar;
            }
            is.close();
            return targetString;
        } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Base.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Reader, that lazily accesses the ResultSet.

```
try (Reader reader = rs.getNCharacterStream(...)) {
    if (reader == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    reader.transferTo(writer);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

A null reader is allowed in a try-with-resources.

---

As `transferTo` exists since java 10, here an alternative.

```
    char[] buf = new buf[1024];
    for (;;) {
        int nread = reader.read(buf);
        if (nread == -1) {
            break;
        }
        writer.write(buf, 0, nread);
    }
```

Comment: The line "reader.transferTo(writer);" produces the error: cannot find symbol.

Comment: [`Reader.transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#transferTo(java.io.Writer)) exists only since java 10. But reading all in a loop should pose no problem.

Comment: Yes I use a loop, but rs.getNCharacterStream only get 32K char.
You can see it here:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vHk_yS-wSj0/XYEzSocvi8I/AAAAAAAAAL4/0HXUGcv2OSEYXjgrb3rxs8iR48JurJXggCK8BGAsYHg/s0/2019-09-17.png

Comment: And the table column is a CLOB/NCLOB? Then it is time to worry about what really is stored in the DB. By the way String += is very (markedly) slow.

Comment: Is a text column, in dba_views. but I solved it with ResultSet getBinaryStream function. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check your DB and driver version.

`getString`works for me for LONG column with length > 32K

Example

```
SELECT TEXT_LENGTH  FROM DBA_VIEWS where owner = 'SYS' and VIEW_NAME= 'DBA_STREAMS_COLUMNS';

TEXT_LENGTH
-----------
      36331
```

This snipped

```
 def rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TEXT  FROM DBA_VIEWS where owner = 'SYS' and VIEW_NAME= 'DBA_STREAMS_COLUMNS'")

 while(rs.next())
  {
   String txt = rs.getString(1)  
   println "got txt    ${txt.take(10)}...${txt.reverse().take(10).reverse()}, size: ${txt.length()}"
  }
```

returns

```
got txt    select dis...     ) = 0, size: 36331
```

Used versions

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
DriverVersion 12.1.0.2.0
```

Comment: I have ojdbc8.jar. But don't works. The limit is 32767 using these functions: getNCharacterStream, getString, getNString.

Comment: @RonnyV time to upgrade? Alternatively you must stream, this should work even in [Oracle 8](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/java.816/a81354/basic4.htm#1002507)

Comment: Yes, that is the solution, thank you:

java.io.InputStream is = resultados.getBinaryStream(columna);